# Is there any trigger to know if an attachment from an item in a list is downloaded?

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, microsoft-flow

So I'm planning to make a sharepoint list system (with microsoft flow). There's this case, if someone downloaded an attachment from an item, there's this status column that'll change text to "File downloaded".

Is there any way in microsoft flow or sharepoint itself to know if an attachment from an item in a list is downloaded by a user (who's permission is read only)?

Or is there any way to know that information? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Through auditing, SharePoint can track file downloads. But auditing is a report rather than a real time trigger. I'm not sure you can catch the event in real time, if that's necessary?!

Check out [Logging people who download files in SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/139815/logging-people-who-download-files-in-sharepoint).